# Await.result or just a simple call?

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

I'm trying to deal with `futures`. Is there a major difference between these two?

```
//1
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def longRequestToServer(): String = {...}
val future = Future { longRequestToServer() }
val resultAsync = Await.result(future, 60.seconds)
```

and

```
//2 
val resultSync = try {
  longRequestToServer()
} catch {
  case _: Exception => "???"
}
```

except the time period of `60 seconds` in the first case.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sourcedelica, trying to figure out the difference between them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Blocking is evil.

Blocking in a future and then waiting on the result consumes two threads instead of one.

Is that twice as evil?

It's the blocking call you want to avoid.

(In a future, you'd at least want to wrap it in `blocking` to make it half as evil.  The precise ratio is actually .666 evil.)

Edit: Something else to consider is that the two versions may have different behavior on shutdown.  In the first case, the future can be rejected.  Coordinating these effects, especially with multiple custom executors and callbacks, is relatively subtle and error-prone. (This is when people prefer actors to futures.)

(Early on, futures weren't entirely robust for all throwables, so you could fail to see an error on a worker thread, but AFAIK that is fixed.)

Comment: @maasg I was going for pithy rather than, you know, sarcastic. Because it's a lesson worth learning over and again, I find from personal experience.

Comment: it's evil and so what of it? the question is about comparison the two blocks of the code.

Comment: @Alex The comparison is that `waiting on the result consumes two threads instead of one.`  I stand by my pithiness.  I suggest to see the forest instead of one or two trees.

Comment: so the second approach is better?

Comment: That's a different question. :)  There is no benefit in the first given the cost, unless you're doing more parallel work than you show and also do `blocking(...)`. But if you must block and you have other things to do at the same time, then it is worth it.

Answer (score 4):

So there are two difference between those two.

The second one is a bog standard non-async call where you wait on the return of the method and block the current thread as you do so and do error handling afterwards.

The first one is in my opinion a step in the right direction. You start your long-running task in a future and don't block on the original thread, but since you use Await.result you actually create a second thread and then block the first one ending up using more resources then previous, but you also don't do any error handling.

What you should do instead is using a callback: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

```
val future = Future { longRequestToServer() }
future onSuccess {
  case result => doSomething(result)
}
future onFailure {
  case t => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

Thereby having the advantage of not blocking your thread with a long background calculation and having error management.

Of course there are moments where it is sensible to use Await.result but most of the time you can write a non-blocking variant with callbacks.

Comment: If you want a direct answer to you question: 

if you use Await.result(future, Infinity) then the two difference between them is that in the first solution you use two threads and don't do any error handling and in the second solution you use one thread and you do error handling. 

That's why I proposed a better way to be both more efficient and do error handling, so that someone who don't know about callbacks finds an answer that helps him.

Comment: 'More efficient and do error handling'? In which way? I do not know about people who use futures and never heard about the callbacks. But, for those who are aware of the callbacks, this is a complete bullshit.

Comment: Await in the end has no effect and [Await in the loop is more efficient than Await in the end](http://valjok.blogspot.com.ee/2016/09/awaitresult-is-faster-than-pure-futures.html)